# In this block of Python3 code, what does the "1" do in the parenthesis of the sum function?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures

Here is the code that I am struggling with understanding.  Most specifically, I am struggling to wrap my mind around count = sum(1 for elem in nums if elem == num).  Can somebody please explain it to me?

Thanks a ton!

```
class Solution:
def majorityElement(self, nums):
    majority_count = len(nums)//2
    for num in nums:
        count = sum(1 for elem in nums if elem == num)
        if count > majority_count:
            return num
```

Given an array nums of size n, return the majority element.

The majority element is the element that appears more than ⌊n / 2⌋ times. You may assume that the majority element always exists in the array.

The code works for the algorithm problem, I just need to better understand why.  The prompt of the problem is thus:

Given an array nums of size n, return the majority element.

The majority element is the element that appears more than ⌊n / 2⌋ times. You may assume that the majority element always exists in the array.

Comment: It adds `1` for each `elem` in `nums` where `elem` is equal to `num`. Effectively counting them.